# Cannot open Android App only after updating Expo. error: package 'expo.modules' does not exist

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I have a `React-Native` project. This project begun with `Expo` then it has been ejected switched to `react-native`. the `expo` libraries is still in use, so I was forced to update `expo` and migrate from `react-native-unimodules` to expo modules

I have used all the references available in the bellow links

- [Expo/Fyi - Migrating to expo modules](https://github.com/expo/fyi/blob/main/expo-modules-migration.md)
- [Medium-Migrate from unimodules to expo modules](https://dev.to/wbroek/migrate-from-react-native-unimodules-to-expo-modules-25c6)
- [Expo-guides](https://docs.expo.dev/bare/installing-expo-modules/#automatic-installation)

I have succeeded to let it work on IOS, but on android i am still stuck for hours with the following errors

> **error: package expo.modules does not exist** ...import expo.modules.ApplicationLifecycleDispatcher;

I think that the expo.modules libraries is not initializing on android, even that i have configured all the mentioned steps in Expo documents

Can someone figure out what is the problem

Here is a screen shoot on the list of errors that is appearing
[image]
& Here is the mainApplication.java:

```js
package com.myapp.app;
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import com.facebook.react.PackageList;
import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.reactcommunity.rndatetimepicker.RNDateTimePickerPackage;
import com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;
//import com.teamvate.app.generated.BasePackageList;

//import org.unimodules.adapters.react.ModuleRegistryAdapter;
// import org.unimodules.adapters.react.ReactModuleRegistryProvider;
// import org.unimodules.core.interfaces.Package;
// import org.unimodules.core.interfaces.SingletonModule;

//import expo.modules.updates.UpdatesController;

import expo.modules.ApplicationLifecycleDispatcher;
import expo.modules.ReactNativeHostWrapper;

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.List;


// import javax.annotation.Nullable;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {
//  private final ReactModuleRegistryProvider mModuleRegistryProvider = new ReactModuleRegistryProvider(
//    new BasePackageList().getPackageList()
//  );

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHostWrapper(this, new ReactNativeHost(this) {
    @Override
    public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
      return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
      List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
      // packages.add(new ModuleRegistryAdapter(mModuleRegistryProvider));
      // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
      packages.add(new ApplicationLifecycleDispatcher());
      return packages;
    }

    @Override
    protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
      return "index";
    }

    // @Override
    // protected @Nullable String getJSBundleFile() {
    //   if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
    //     return super.getJSBundleFile();
    //   } else {
    //     return UpdatesController.getInstance().getLaunchAssetFile();
    //   }
    // }

    // @Override
    // protected @Nullable String getBundleAssetName() {
    //   if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
    //     return super.getBundleAssetName();
    //   } else {
    //     return UpdatesController.getInstance().getBundleAssetName();
    //   }
    // }
  });

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);

    // if (!BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
    //   UpdatesController.initialize(this);
    // }

    initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager());
    ApplicationLifecycleDispatcher.onApplicationCreate(this);
  }
   @Override
   public void onConfigurationChanged(@NonNull Configuration newConfig) {
     super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
     ApplicationLifecycleDispatcher.onConfigurationChanged(this, newConfig);
   }
  /**
   * Loads Flipper in React Native templates. Call this in the onCreate method with something like
   * initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager());
   *
   * @param context
   * @param reactInstanceManager
   */
  private static void initializeFlipper(
      Context context, ReactInstanceManager reactInstanceManager) {
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
      try {
        /*
         We use reflection here to pick up the class that initializes Flipper,
        since Flipper library is not available in release mode
        */
        Class<?> aClass = Class.forName("com.myapp.app.ReactNativeFlipper");
        aClass
            .getMethod("initializeFlipper", Context.class, ReactInstanceManager.class)
            .invoke(null, context, reactInstanceManager);
      } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java class files `ApplicationLifecycleDispatcher` and `ReactNativeHostWrapper` are found in the npm module `expo`, the main package for expo. There could be a problem with this package.

Verify that in your package.json has a dependency of

`"expo": ">=44.0.0-0 <45.0.0",`

you can run `yarn --check-files` to ensure the files are correct.

Also,

Ensure you using the latest Expo CLI; expo-cli@5.0.2 or greater is required.

`npm i -g expo-cli`

Ensure you are using the latest Expo EAS CLI;

`npm i -g eas-cli`

Verify that when you run `expo upgrade` you get no errors.

Comment: Hello Mark.. Thank u for ur reply.. I have tried and applied all of ur recommendation, but still stuck with another error.. Settings file '/Users/...app/android/settings.gradle' line: 7 A problem occurred evaluating settings '... dev app'. > Could not read script '/Users/.../app/node_modules/expo/scripts/autolinking.gradle' as it does not exist. * 
  **Note  that the files ... node_modules/expo/scripts/autolinking.gradle is already available in the project node modules folder**    I think there is something with the project path